# Particle Instance Modifier to Inherent Color from Hair Particles

Tags: particles, hair, texture-coordinates

Does anyone know how to inherent the color from hair particles and assign that too a particle instance modifier object, im basically attaching tiny balls to the end of the hair, and the goal is to have the balls be the same color as the hair it is attached too but then have an emissive property, like a glowing colored tip.

I thought it would be through the From Instancer in the texture coordinate node, but that doesnt seem to work.[image]

Thanks for any advice.